# iOS 15.5 Auto Update causing wifi drops with router

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, router

Last night Apple auto-updated my iPhone 8 Plus and installed iOS 15.5. I've gone through many such updates for years with no problems. Beginning today with the first use of my iPhone, the WiFi connection dropped repeatedly.  I went to Settings and turned WiFi off and then back on and reestablished a connection, but it lasted only a short time -- maybe 15 seconds -- and then dropped again.

I've tested all other devices served by the router and my updated iPhone is the only one with this problem.

Router is ASUS RTN66R  Double 450 Mbps N Router.  Serving 6 devices.

Comment: One thing to try is to go to Settings > WiFi > tap the information icon on the WiFi network, then Forget the WiFi network and recreate it. See if that helps. In most cases when I've had funky WiFi problems, simply tearing down and rebuilding the WiFi helps tremendously.

Comment: Thank you. I believe that is my fix.

Comment: If this solved your problem, accept the answer below.

Comment: I’ve been asked to accept this answer. I do not see where to do that.  I do accept. It solves my problem.

Comment: Simple! https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

One thing to try is to go to Settings > WiFi > tap the information icon on the WiFi network, then Forget the WiFi network and recreate it.

In most cases when I've had funky WiFi problems, simply tearing down and rebuilding the WiFi helps tremendously.